# Bootstrap, h1 overlay on a background image within a container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background, overlay

```
<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <!--Giant Background Pic-->
    <img class ="bckground" src="images/napaliWall.jpg">
    <h1> Title Text </h1>
    <p> Sand sand sand sand</p>
    </div>
</div>


.bckground{
  background-size: cover;
  background: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  max-height:100%;
  max-width:100%;

}
```

My h1 and p are not overlaying on the background image. What is the proper way to do this within bootstrap's container? I don't want to make the text a fixed position because I fear it may mess with the responsiveness of my webpage for mobile. I simply want my background image to fill the row-column container it is in and to have to text on top of it. my HTML code is wrapped inside a div container, it is just not shown.

Comment: It would be good if you created a [mcve]. Right now your example is not complete. We do not know if you are using Bootstrap v3 or v4 and also the `<img>` asset is unknown. Please provide an absolute path so it loads properly. Use the snippet tool (`<>` button) or a snippet website - jsFiddle, codepen, etc.

Answer (score 0):

you should set the image at the background in css

like background-url: (url to image)